# How to edit the text of a textView using viewbinding?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I am new to kotlin and android and I just started getting into using viewbindings.
Im trying to make this locations app and when setting the date through a datepickerdialog, when i try to edit the text of a textview with a binding its giving me errors. Can someone help me?

private fun displaySelectedDate(timestamp : Long){

```
    binding?.etDate?.text = format.format(timestamp)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: required Editable?
found String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to

```
binding?.etDate?.setText(format.format(timestamp))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the docs for `EditText`, you'll find a `setText()` method. It takes in a `String` and a `TextView.BufferType`. For example:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
editText.setText("This sets the text.", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

It also inherits `TextView`'s `setText(CharSequence)` and `setText(int)` methods, so you can set it just like a regular `TextView`:

```
editText.setText("Hello world!");
editText.setText(R.string.hello_world);
```

Comment: Hello Augustine, I managed to find a solution using R.id.name, but I dont want to use that since its an "old" technology. I was wondering if i could find a solution while still using binding

Comment: If this is not it then I need to see the error ..................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Date date = new Date(location.getTime());
DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
mTimeText.setText("Time: " + dateFormat.format(date));